# nodejs & mongojs, keep getting null for get method with findOne

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongojs

here is the code:

```
var express = require('express');
var router = express.Router();
var mongojs = require('mongojs');
var db = mongojs('mongodb://mike:mike@localhost:27017/mytasklist', ['tasks']);


router.get('/task/:id', function(req, res, next) {
    db.tasks.findOne({ _id: mongojs.ObjectId(req.params.id) }, function(err, task) {
        if (err) {
            res.send(err);
        }
        res.json(task);
    });
});
```

MongoDB is up and running, I keep getting Null on the screen

[a screenshot of the result of Getting All the data.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kF7te.png)

Comment: Well, are you **sure** that you're passing a correct parameter and that an object with that `_id` exists in that collection? Can you post an output from the mongo shell showing that object and perhaps a screenshot of the failed query?

Comment: the "_id" does exist, the _id is default made by mongodb itself,
this is a screenshot of the Get All the results from the same collection, it works fine, for the Ger One method, I copy the _id of one of the results and put it in the url, but i just get a big NULL of the screen.

Comment: You'll have to add the image to the question, not an absolute path to the image on your pc :P

Comment: @MilanVelebit haha, I thought it would upload it like that, I just added a screenshot to the question, top there. :)

Comment: sorry, I found the problem, I used a json generator to get some data and fill the database with, my bad was there that I forgot that the _id will be generated by the MongoDB itself, i was giving it a id also! :D \r\n this json generator https://www.json-generator.com/# \r\n